# Azure AD Premium for AWS?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm considering **Azure AD Premium** for Identity Management service for my newly created ASP.NET web applications hosted in **AWS** cloud. Is **Azure AD Premium** works as Identity Management in **AWS** cloud? I'm assuming Azure AD Premium is a standalone product and can be work as stand alone or under ANY cloud environment. I'm exploring it so ANY input will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. An Azure AD integrated application could be running in any cloud (even in an on-premises server). None of the [authentication scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx) of Azure AD dictate where the application is hosted.

Hope this helps.